# Object Reference Not Set ... Debugging Stored Procedure in Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, debugging

I'm working on updating a stored procedure that is called to update a user. This stored procedure needs to also create a description of what was updated for auditing purposes. However when debugging in Visual Studio I get!

[image: screenshot]

All of my input values are valid, I leave none null, and my update_* procedures **without** the *action_taken* value are working. I'm seemingly writing something incorrectly, but I haven't figured out what.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_user`(
in requestor_id BIGINT(20),
in user_id BIGINT(20),
in department_id BIGINT(20),
in location_id BIGINT(20),
in shift_id BIGINT(20),
in first_name VARCHAR(45),
in last_name VARCHAR(45),
in email VARCHAR(45),
in phone VARCHAR(45),
in security_stamp LONGTEXT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE queried_username VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE action_taken VARCHAR(255);
    SET action_taken = '';

    SELECT
        users.username
    INTO
        queried_username
    FROM users 
    WHERE users.id=user_id
    LIMIT 1;

    IF (queried_username IS NULL) THEN
    BEGIN
    END;

IF (department_id != users.department_id) THEN
    SET action_taken = CONCAT(action_taken, '[Department Updated]');
END IF;
IF (location_id != users.location_id) THEN
    SET action_taken = CONCAT(action_taken, '[Location Updated]');
END IF;
IF (shift_id != users.shift_id) THEN
    SET action_taken = CONCAT(action_taken, '[Shift Updated]');
END IF;
IF (first_name != users.first_name) THEN
    SET action_taken = CONCAT(action_taken, '[First Name Updated]');
END IF;
IF (last_name != users.last_name) THEN
    SET action_taken = CONCAT(action_taken, '[Last Name Updated]');
END IF;
IF (email != users.email) THEN
    SET action_taken = CONCAT(action_taken, '[Email Updated]');
END IF;
IF (phone != users.phone) THEN
    SET action_taken = CONCAT(action_taken, '[Phone Updated]');
END IF;

    BEGIN
        UPDATE users SET 
            users.department_id=department_id, 
            users.location_id=location_id, 
            users.shift_id=shift_id,
            users.first_name=first_name,
            users.last_name=last_name,
            users.email=email,
            users.phone=phone,
            users.modified=NOW(),
            users.security_stamp=security_stamp
        WHERE users.id=user_id;

        CALL update_audit_log(
            requestor_id, 
            user_id,
            null,
            department_id, 
            location_id, 
            shift_id, 
            null,
            "User Administration", 
            CONCAT(
                'Modified user (id="',
                user_id,
                '", username="',
                queried_username,
                '") | Action= ',
                action_taken
            )
        );
    END;
    END IF;
END
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The comparisons in the `IF` statements needed to be to a queried variable, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    users.username
INTO
    queried_username
FROM users 
WHERE users.id=user_id
LIMIT 1;
```

Then you can compare using `NOT LIKE` like:

```
IF (username NOT LIKE queried_username) THEN
    SET action_taken = CONCAT(action_taken, '[Username Updated]');
END IF;
```

Don't forget to `DECLARE` each variable before assigning them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `DELIMITER` statements around the `CREATE...`?

Does VS have any way to debug Stored Routines?  (I suspect not.)

The failure to do it this way could cause trouble later:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ... from users ... FOR UPDATE;
various SETs
UPDATE ...;
COMMIT;
```

Another consideration...  An "audit trail" may be better achieved via a `TRIGGER` wherein you can compare `NEW.` to `OLD.`.

Comment: No DELIMITER, and VS 2013 at least does have Stored Procedure Debugging. In Server Explorer, you can right click > Debug Stored Procedure and enter parameters. It will then execute the SP and if you have breakpoints set it will allow you to step through. I can step through the other procedures, just not this one although the mysql is validated in mysql workbench.

Comment: Thanks for your help though. I found that the delimiter declaration was added when the script was applied through MySQL workbench 6.3